# Shelf object in python without the library

Tags: python

I am trying to create a shelf object to add tools to it where I will have :

-position of the shelf on the wall (between 0 and 4)

-array of objects of type tool (maximum of 10 items per shelf).

The constructor should set the position of the shelf but should not set any tools.
And where I will also be able to add tools to the shelf. Each position has a 10 max index list. When adding a new tool I want the tool to be appended to the array in the next available position. So a position with already a full 10 index list is unavailable. This is my code:

```
class shelf():

    def __init__(self, position = 0): #Contructor sets the position of the shelf but not the tool
        self.position = position

    def add_tool_to_shelf(self,tool):
        tool_list = [[] for i in range(5)] #Actual shelf 2D array

        for len(tool_list[self.position]) in range(10):
            if self.position == 5:
                print("The shelf is full!")
                break
            else:
                tool_list[self.position].append(tool)
                self.position += 1
```

This code gives me a syntax error : "cannot assign to function call" on the `for len(tool_list[self.position]) in range(10):` line. Can someone help me out please?

PD: The tools that will be added to the shelf will also be objects atributes, later in the code I would like to access a shelf slot and output the atributes of the tool stored there. I would like to create just one class for the shelf.

Comment: I have changed the for loop to a while loop; while len(tool_list[self.postion]) < 10:

Comment: See this policy on asking homework questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

The error your getting is because for loop is trying to iterate a function over an iterable.

In python, you have what are called iterables, which are classes that can be crawled over. They have a defined start and a call to get the next element for instance a list, range and tuple are all iterables see https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.

The range function is an iterable and will return back a new number (or object etc of whatever its iterating over) each time. It will try and give this to whatver is passed before the `in`. In this case `len(tool_list[self.position])`.

However `len(tool_list[self.position])` is itself a function that will return a number. So in many ways your actually saying (if the len was 5) `for 5 in range(5)` which clearly won't work as `5` is a literal and not a variable and as such cannot be set to the updated value.

When your using a for loop the first item must be a variable so it can take the value of whatever the current state of the iterable is. It cannot be a function call (as len() is).